# AV tag is used for two different things

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I [reviewed](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5791734) a new wiki excerpt for the [av](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/av)-tag.
It contains the explanation that AV stands for Anti-Virus, whereas I know it as an abbreviation of Audio/Video.

When looking at [questions tagged with it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/av), both are used. Although 'Audio/Video' seems to be the main usage.

Furthermore, SO already has the [antivirus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/antivirus)-tag.

Should we remove the [av](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/av)-tag for all antivirus related questions? Or is 'AV' a commonly used abbreviation for AntiVirus as well?

Comment: In my opinion, [tag:av] should be a synonym for a more descriptive tag on audio/video, and purged of antivirus-related questions.

Comment: I also got the tag av for review. In my opinion it is too ambiguous to be useful.

Comment: The tag excerpt is approved now... But it seems that the tag is almost gone... :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While `av` is a common English acronym for [audio-visual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/audio-visual), I don't believe it is acceptable or necessary in that form - and its usage may vary depending on region. There are no questions tagged as `audio-visual`, so we don't need a contracted version of it.
The same goes for its usage as an acronym for [antivirus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/antivirus) - there is simply no need to have such an abbreviated tag, especially when it has multiple possible meanings.

I would suggest it is burninated and possibly blacklisted till there is something it can be legitimately applied to. There are only <strike>21</strike> <strike>9</strike> **0** questions with this tag so it is an easy cleanup.

Comment: Getting rid of the tag and just their 'unabreviated' forms, sounds like a good solution to prevent (further) confusion.

Comment: It's down to 0. I slapped a "DO NOT USE" comment on the wiki summary (not that anyone using it before it gets purged will read it anyway...)

Comment: I've always seen `a/v` for `audio-visual` or the more traditional `audio/video`, so unless `/`s aren't allowed in tags it really should be that, which would free `av` for `antivirus`