# General recommendation: Should a tag be unambiguous

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

I was about to edit the wiki page of [survey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/survey).

However, I noticed it is used for different things.

- the [R package survey](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survey/index.html)
- survey (data and projects) in general
- maybe more

In the related question [Multiple meaning of 'ctools' tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288347/multiple-meaning-of-ctools-tag) it was recommended

> Instead of just keeping ctools ambiguous, or forcing it to mean the
>   Drupal ctools, I propose we just split it up into drupal-ctools and
>   pentaho-ctools.

My question here is: Is this a general recommendation? Should a tag be unambiguous?

I guess, there are exceptions to that rule, e.g. `survey` is also a common English word. This aspect is somewhat similar to [AV tag is used for two different things](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271531/av-tag-is-used-for-two-different-things)

Comment: A tag should help people find questions. Tags like [multiple] are useless to get any sort of sensible grouping. That seems less so for survey.

Comment: "Tags are a means of connecting experts with questions they will be able to answer by sorting questions into **specific, well-defined categories.**" I say follow the help center.

Comment: "Should a tag be unambiguous" Generally yes, but sometimes product naming (and far worse: product rebranding) just makes that really hard to accomplish.

Comment: Yes — tags should be unambiguous. See [Reconciling archive files with augmented reality — ar vs augmented-reality](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366520/reconciling-archive-files-with-augmented-reality-ar-vs-augmented-reality).  If people want to search for the (Unix/POSIX standard) `ar` command, they do not want to see all the augmented reality (or aspect ratio or auto-regression) questions too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a strong smell that this tag should be burninated instead of disambiguated.  If the tag is too broad then there's a good chance that it fails [the criteria for a tag to remain](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/250934/1079354).

This would be a good candidate to start the formal burnination process on.

Answer (score -3):

Explicit is better than implicit ...

Comment: That goes for answers, too!